# Eclipselink primary key unique constraint issue

Tags: oracle, eclipselink

I am facing the unique constraint issue while inserting the data. Having the similar code setup mentioned above. I have restarted my application server in both local and PCF after DB restart but still the issue exists.

I am migrating from Hibernate to Eclipselink. I am new to Eclipselink. After running through multiple sites, I have set the allocation size to 1 in my entity.

Using Sequence generator and using Sequence having my Oracle database.

Questions:
 1. Eclipselink pick some old primary key I'd (10,679 instead of next I'd 50067899)...any suggestions in which scenarios it will pick old ID's? 
2.Any persistence property is there for sequence generation?

Comment: No sequence setup would pick 10,679 out of the air- what is your ID sequencing setup?  I'd bet you set it up against an older sequence in the database or one used for something else by mistake.

Comment: 1. Having Sequence named "MSG_ID_SEQ" in database. 
Min number :1
Max number : 9999999999999999999999
Increment by : 1
Last number : 10680
Cache size: 0

Comment: 1. Having Sequence named "MSG_ID_SEQ" in database. 
Min number :1
Max number : 9999999999999999999999
Increment by : 1
Last number : 10680
Cache size: 0

2. When we tried a existing version (JPA + Hibernate) ,when we try it application deployed environment, it generates the id somethig 50000234, but wen we try from local it is generating lower number 10679. In both case, referring same database instance and sequence name. And Sequence Last number not getting updated as well.

Comment: Also, in existing production version, not sure why the LAST Number in sequence not getting updated though it generates the primary key properly in table. Any idea could help me to understand it?. Is always we can identify the next primary key from Last number in sequence ?

Comment: You have to show your annotation/sequence definition. Sounds like you are using a different sequence with the other provider, but it isn't clear what you mean by local vs application deployed environment - are there other settings that might be getting picked up in the different environments?

Comment: Thanks Chris for your response. I have missed a cheeky things to understand hibernate. Hibernate having default allocation size 50, so the primary key generation happens using formula Last Number in Sequence multiplies with allocation size (10680*50).  Now, EclipseLink seems having different primary key generation concept. Any idea please let me know on that.

Comment: EclipseLink requests the next batch of numbers from the sequence object to determine what it can allocate.  So if your sequence returns 10680, it means it is able to use (10680-x to 10680) where X is the increment by value. This is where/why it got the 10679 value. It would have displayed this value prior to EclipseLink getting and incrementing it.

Comment: EclipseLink also uses a default preallocation strategy of 50, so this shouldn't have been a multiplication of the sequence value returned. When 10680 is returned, any JPA provider should have used a +- of 50 from this value (I've read Hibernate uses the sequence value slightly different from EclipseLink, using the next 50 instead of the last 50, but can't confirm this personally). You need to fix your sequence to match up with the last ID value assigned, starting over from there. I don't see how 10680*50 can possibly be construed without using some custom sequence impl within Hibernate

Comment: Thanks Chris for your response. Yesterday I have done some scenarios to extract the behavior of EclipseLink for Primary Generation.
Scenario 1:
DB Sequence : Increment By 1;Cache 0; Last Number 10680
Entity : Default allocation Size (50)
Result: Primary Generation starts from 10631.. 
Once it has reached the Primary Key number 10680, Last Number increased to 10681 and the Primary Key generation starts from 10632, this causes unique constraint error, as this number already generated primarily.

Comment: You are telling JPA that it is getting 50 numbers while the DB is only giving out 1. The DB sequence object's increment value needs to match JPA's allocation size.

Comment: @Chirs. Thanks. Matching the allocation size with increment by 50. Resolved the issue. To summarize, Hibernate follows LastNumber*AllocationSize (50) and EclipseLink follows LastNumber - Allocation size (50).